# Gauss–Seidel convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I use Gauss–Seidel method to solve linear equations $Ax=b$. Before applying the method I convert the system to $A^TAx=A^Tb$. After $N$ iterations the method just stops improving previous solution. What can be wrong?

Comment: If $A^T A$ is not definite positive (i.e. only non-definite positive), the method may not converge. In a sense this is normal since $A$ does not have a full range. Do you know something about the kernel/image of $A$?

Comment: $detA \not= 0$ and $A^TA\ge 0$ then $A^TA>0$. Right? Then it must converge. After about 3 iterations the previous solution equals the next solution over and over again.

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Perhaps you should try out your program on some small matrix example, for example on one where you may compare with the solution explicitly?

Comment: $A^TA$: $[[12002.203671015004,1034.703828357454],[1034.703828357454,89.20168535023822]]$

$A^Tb$: $[-389256.3686967812, -33557.55441018976]$

Exact solution: $[-40.58214620213145, 94.53798540920776]$

Method solution: $[-32.51947315372263, 1.0142068255692673]$

Comment: If $A^TA\ge 0$ then $\lambda_i \ge 0$ and $detA^TA\ge 0$.

Comment: Your matrix seems to have eigenvalues around 0.00039 and 12091.4.. This is probably too close to being singular for the method to work properly.

Comment: You should wright $A$ and $b$ on the question so that people can handle the problem.